# Passing initial values from wordpress to vuex

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, vuex

I am working on building a custom taxonomy landing page on a wordpress site using vuejs. 
I am using vuex for state management but am currently stuck with a problem. for few variable like "slug" I don't know how to pass initial value to the store. I am using wp_localize_script to send value from wordpress but vuejs does not recognize the variable.

Archive.php

```
wp_register_script( 'archive-vue-chunk', THEME_JAVASCRIPT_URI . '/archive_js/dist/assets/chunk-vendors.js',array('site-2017'),null,true);
wp_register_script( 'archive-vue', THEME_JAVASCRIPT_URI . '/archive_js/dist/assets/app.js',array('archive-vue-chunk'),null,true);
$term  = get_queried_object();
$slug  = $term->slug; 

wp_localize_script ( 'archive-vue', 'initialvaluestovue', array (
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url ( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'slug'    => $slug 
    ) );
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Archive from './Archive.vue'
import store from './store'


Vue.config.productionTip = false 

new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(Archive),
  propsData:{ initialvaluestovue }
}).$mount('#archive_using_vuejs')
```

Any help is very much appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed main.js to as follows and was able to get the value in Archive.vue

main.js

```
new Vue({
store,
 render: h => {
   const context = {
   props: {
     initialvaluestovue : window.initialvaluestovue
   }
 };
 return h(Archive, context)
}   
}).$mount('#archive_using_vuejs')
```

I was able to display the pass object in archive.vue

Archive.vue

```
<template>
<div class="layout">{{initialvaluestovue}}</div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
name: 'Archive',    
props:{
    initialvaluestovue:{
        type: Object
    }
 }
}
</script>
```